# Script in Google Sheets which deletes every column that doesn't have a header

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to take an [existing script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107519/script-in-google-sheets-which-deletes-every-column-that-doesnt-have-a-specific) but change it so that every column that is *without* a header is deleted.

```
function deleteColumns() {
  var required = ["Name", "Position", "Salary"];

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var width = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, width).getValues()[0];
  for (var i = headers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (required.indexOf(headers[i]) == -1) {
      sheet.deleteColumn(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

I thought this might work but it doesn't

```
if (ISBLANK(required.indexOf(headers[i]) == -1)) {
  sheet.deleteColumn(i+1);
}
```

referenceError : ISBLANK is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

You confuse Google Sheet Formulas like `ISBLANK` with Google Apps Script which uses JavaScript.

In JavaScript there is no built in method `ISBLANK` nor it is **defined** in your code and hence the error: `this method is not defined`.

To delete **every** column with an empty header, all you need to do in JavaScript is to check whether the header value is empty and if so delete the corresponding column:

```
if (headers[i] == '') {
    sheet.deleteColumn(i+1);
}
```

### Solution:

Keep in mind that this script is executed on the active sheet. Namely, the sheet that is currently **selected** in the spreadsheet file.

```
function deleteColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var width = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, width).getValues()[0];
  for (var i = headers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (headers[i] == '') {
      sheet.deleteColumn(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! thank you so much. Your insight has just solved three other sheets Vs JavaScript misunderstandings I had.